# Zebra RFD8500 : How to use read in ZETI

Tags: rfid

I have a Zebra RFD8500 here and I connected to it via the terminal. I am trying to use the ZETI command `read` to access epc's, but it does not read anything.
But if I use the ZETI command `inventory` it finds all the tags around.

Anyone knows how to use the read command properly? Also is there some kind of filter per default on?

I am using the developer example on page 174 [Link to PDF](https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/manuals/MN002222A01a.pdf)

Comment: I worked with Zebra devices a year ago, and wrote a tip that might (then again, it might not) help you. Anyway, it might be worth your time looking at it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/802428/How-to-send-a-command-to-a-Zebra-QLn-Printer-from

Comment: Thx for the tip, but I did not run into that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you solved this problem, but I couldn't find anything else via Google. I had the same problem with using read in ZETI (Zebra RFD8500). The Zebra tech support told me that to use access operations like read and write, you have to turn off dynamic power (which I think is on by default).

Unfortunately, I am not using the iOS API/SDK (writing a custom one for another device), but here's the gist of what you'd be doing:

1. Turn off dynamic power
2. Do an inventory
3. Read some memory bank, like the EPC bank. Optionally, you can also specify access criteria to single out a tag.

To test how this worked in ZETI, I screened into the RFD8500 (on my Mac, doing `ls /dev/tty.RFD*` lists several ttys, I chose the one ending in "-R"):

`screen /dev/tty.RFD8500{long number}-R`

Then I issued these commands:

```
dp .disable
in
rd
```

Commands:

- dp = setdynamicpower
- in = inventory
- rd = read

After issuing "rd", you should be able to see the user memory banks (the default bank for the "rd" command).